# Android - Send SMS without user's assent

Tags: java, android, xml, html, sms

i am making a WEB Java application.
I would like to insert a button which can instantly send an SMS without the user's assent skipping the "Send SMS GUI" (***the user will use the mobile browser to access the service***).

#### Pseudocode Example :

```
If(condition) {
               sendSMSWithNoAssent();
}
```

Comment: it's a WEB JAVA APPLICATION, not an android app

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what a "WEB JAVA APPLICATION" is. That being said, only native Android applications can send SMS without user approval, and then only if the user has granted permission to that app to perform this action.

Comment: "In computing, a web application or web app is a client–server software application which the client (or user interface) runs in a web browser."

and "only native Android applications can send SMS without user approval, and then only if the user has granted permission to that app to perform this action." answers my question. I can't do it without an Android native app